# how to load more than one content type form in one single form

Tags: nodes

i have a book site, where users can upload book details including Author details and i want all this to be captured in one form, but stored separately i.e Author details and book details and i should be able to reference the author in the view display.i don't know how best to describe this but the link to the site is naijabooker.com and the form is at http://naijabooker.com/premium-book, the output dispaly link is at http://naijabooker.com/title. thanks for anticipated help this is a drupal 7 site